# SIOCSIFNETMASK: Invalid argument - Failed to bring up eth0

Tags: linux, ubuntu

`/etc/network/interfaces` looks like this:

```
auto lo eth0

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.15.148
netmask 225.225.225.0
network 192.168.15.0
```

I'm using ubuntu and trying to set a static IP.  Any ideas on what the problem could be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your netmask should be 255.255.255.0 not 225.225.225.0

Comment: which netmasks are allowed?

Comment: netmasks must be on bit-boundaries, with all 1's to the left and all 0's to the right (in binary, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Look like you are on Debian based distribution.

There is a tool called netmask:

```
sudo apt-get install netmask
```

Useful to figure the netmask when you are using CIDR or even Cisco netmask. It detect wrong netmask as well:

```
$ netmask -s 192.168.15.148/24
 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0  
$ netmask -c 192.168.15.148/225.225.225.0
 netmask: invalid mask 0xe1e1e100 from "225.225.225.0"
```

Quicker than reading a netmask table, it show the range of available IP in a network:

```
$ netmask -r 192.168.15.148/30
 192.168.15.148-192.168.15.151  (4)
```

Comment: That's only a sort of related answer, isn't it?  I mean, it leads to the right answer, but it's circuitous.